# Pandas: Spare data, groupby and datetime extension into new dataframe?

Tags: datetime, pandas, indexing

Have been reading a couple of very good posts in here for the last days and unfortunately, I think its my turn right now as I have the following problem:

I read in a large dataframe (df) from csv, incl. c.20 columns and all types of variables incl. float, object, string, integer and datetime. Datetime is not recognized, so I first converted the respective object column - lets call it 'pup' and normalized it (as I only needed daily level for further processing) in another column:

```
df.pub = pd.to_datetime(df.pub, format='%d/%m/%Y  %H:%M')
df['pub_day'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df.pub).normalize()
df.set_index(['pub']) # indexing in df remained accurate
```

This works all fine. Now, I performed a couple of groupby operations (=countifs) of various further columns conditional on 'pub_day'. Again, these worked all fine and aggregate numbers where all correct. I.e:

```
df['counted_if'] = df['some_no'].groupby(df['pub_day']).transform('sum')
```

I have no continuous 'pub' or 'pub_day' column, meaning some days are completely missing in my csv and some have multiple occurences.

NOW HERE COMES THE PROBLEM:
What I wanted to do next is to write the correctly computed groupby operations as new columns in a new dataframe df2 in continuous format, meaning adding rows for missing days in 'pup_day' and deleting such rows which contain a particular day for the second time. FYI: When I just add a new column for a groupby operation in my first df, the groupby values are still correct and just duplicated when a day in 'pub_day' appears more than once.

I tried houndreds of things and also read a lot about reindex incl. fill_value, set_index and many more but still I could not figure it out.

Hence, how to: (1) export column ['count-if'] into a 2nd dataframe? (2) set day-based datetime column 'pup-day' as df2 index? (3) delete duplicated entries in this 1column/1index df2? (4) manipulate index in a way, that all days appear incl. empty days, so that I finally have a discrete time-series on a daily basis?

Seriously, I know all the steps (1)-(4) by myself but somehow, they only seem to work when tested stand-alone... My combined code is messy, has lots of lines and gives indexing errors.... Is there any fast 5-10 lined workaround for all this?

### UPDATE: THIS IS THE BROADER PICTURE IN CODE:

--> df Data Sample(some numbers):

```
[1][2]...['some_no'][18]        ['pub']     [20]['pub_day']['counted_if']
ab xy        20      abc   02/02/2002 13:03   2  02/02/2002     24
de it         4      aso   02/02/2002 11:08  32  02/02/2002     24
hi as         3      asd   01/02/2002 17:30   8  01/02/2002      3
zu lu         4      akr   31/01/2002 11:03  12  31/01/2002      5
da fu         1      lts   31/01/2002 09:03  14  31/01/2002      5
la di         6      unu   26/01/2002 08:07   3  26/01/2002      6
.. ..        ..      ..    ..........        ..  ..........      ..
```

--> How it should look like in df2:

```
            ['counted_if']
02/02/2002        24
01/02/2002        3
31/01/2002        5
30/01/2002        0 (or NaN or whatever..)
29/01/2002        0
28/01/2002        0
27/01/2002        0
26/01/2002        6
  .....
```

## One attempt which appeared promising but did not work:

```
df.pub = pd.to_datetime(df.pub, format='%d/%m/%Y  %H:%M')
df['pub_day'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df.pub).normalize()
df.set_index(['pub']) # indexing in df remained accurate

df['counted_if'] = df['some_no'].groupby(df['pub_day']).transform('sum')

df2=df
df2=df2.drop_duplicates(subset['pub_day'],keep='first',inplace=False)
df2=df2.drop(df2.columns[[0,1,2,..,17,21]], axis=1) 
#drops all 20 columns except for df2.counted_if and df2.pub_day
##hence only 2 columns remaining here: pub_day and counted_if    

df2=df2.set_index(['pup_day'])
idx=pd.date_range(min(df2['pub_day']),max(df2['pub_day']))
s = pd.Series(df2.pub_day,df2.counted_if)
s.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(s.index)
s=s.reindex(idx,fill_value=0)
```

Hope this clarifies. Tried many different combinations as well. Solutions highly appreciated!

Comment: Can you add [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Hi, sure will try to extract the lines, please give me c.10-15mins.

Comment: Here you go with an example.

Comment: Thank you. But I need sample of your data - 5 - 6 rows, but solution has to be verifiable.

Comment: Maybe you can modify your question - add input (5,6 rows of sample data), desired output (from input) and what do you try, maybe what is error.

Comment: sure, just did so - here we go!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I give you solution with test data for better testing:

```
import pandas as pd
import io

temp=u"""1;2;some_no;18;pub;20;pub_day;counted_if
ab;xy;20;abc;02/02/2002 13:03;2;02/02/2002;24
de;it;4;aso;02/02/2002 11:08;32;02/02/2002;24
hi;as;3;asd;01/02/2002 17:30;8;01/02/2002;3
zu;lu;4;akr;31/01/2002 11:03;12;31/01/2002;5
da;fu;1;lts;31/01/2002 09:03;14;31/01/2002;5
la;di;6;unu;26/01/2002 08:07;3;26/01/2002;6"""
#after testing replace io.StringIO(temp) to filename
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp), sep=";")
print df
    1   2  some_no   18               pub  20     pub_day  counted_if
0  ab  xy       20  abc  02/02/2002 13:03   2  02/02/2002          24
1  de  it        4  aso  02/02/2002 11:08  32  02/02/2002          24
2  hi  as        3  asd  01/02/2002 17:30   8  01/02/2002           3
3  zu  lu        4  akr  31/01/2002 11:03  12  31/01/2002           5
4  da  fu        1  lts  31/01/2002 09:03  14  31/01/2002           5
5  la  di        6  unu  26/01/2002 08:07   3  26/01/2002           6
```

```
df['pub'] = pd.to_datetime(df.pub, format='%d/%m/%Y  %H:%M')
df['pub_day'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df.pub).normalize()
#added inplace=True
df.set_index('pub', inplace=True) # indexing in df remained accurate
#better syntax of groupby
df['counted_if'] = df.groupby('pub_day')['some_no'].transform('sum')
print df
                      1   2  some_no   18  20    pub_day  counted_if
pub                                                                 
2002-02-02 13:03:00  ab  xy       20  abc   2 2002-02-02          24
2002-02-02 11:08:00  de  it        4  aso  32 2002-02-02          24
2002-02-01 17:30:00  hi  as        3  asd   8 2002-02-01           3
2002-01-31 11:03:00  zu  lu        4  akr  12 2002-01-31           5
2002-01-31 09:03:00  da  fu        1  lts  14 2002-01-31           5
2002-01-26 08:07:00  la  di        6  unu   3 2002-01-26           6

#omited, not necessary
#df2=df
df2=df.drop_duplicates(subset=['pub_day'],keep='first')

#simplier is use subset of data by columns
df2=df2[['counted_if','pub_day']] 
print df2
                     counted_if    pub_day
pub                                       
2002-02-02 13:03:00          24 2002-02-02
2002-02-01 17:30:00           3 2002-02-01
2002-01-31 11:03:00           5 2002-01-31
2002-01-26 08:07:00           6 2002-01-26

#drops all 20 columns except for df2.counted_if and df2.pub_day
##hence only 2 columns remaining here: pub_day and counted_if
```

```
#you have to first reset index before change index to other value
df2.reset_index(inplace=True)
#set column pub_day as index
df2.set_index('pub_day', inplace=True)
#pub_day is index, so use df.index, not df2.pub_day 
idx=pd.date_range(df2.index.min(),df2.index.max())
print idx
DatetimeIndex(['2002-01-26', '2002-01-27', '2002-01-28', '2002-01-29',
               '2002-01-30', '2002-01-31', '2002-02-01', '2002-02-02'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='D')

#series is column counted_if
s = df2.counted_if
print s
pub_day
2002-02-02    24
2002-02-01     3
2002-01-31     5
2002-01-26     6
Name: counted_if, dtype: int64

#index is Datetimeindex, omited
#s.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(s.index)
s=s.reindex(idx,fill_value=0)
print s
2002-01-26     6
2002-01-27     0
2002-01-28     0
2002-01-29     0
2002-01-30     0
2002-01-31     5
2002-02-01     3
2002-02-02    24
Freq: D, Name: counted_if, dtype: int64
```

EDIT by comment:

```
print df
    1   2  some_no   18               pub  20     pub_day  counted_if
0  ab  xy       20  abc  02/02/2002 13:03   2  02/02/2002          24
1  de  it        4  aso  02/02/2002 11:08  32  02/02/2002          24
2  hi  as        3  asd  01/02/2002 17:30   8  01/02/2002           3
3  zu  lu        4  akr  31/01/2002 11:03  12  31/01/2002           5
4  da  fu        1  lts  31/01/2002 09:03  14  31/01/2002           5
5  la  di        6  unu  26/01/2002 08:07   3  26/01/2002           6

df['pub'] = pd.to_datetime(df.pub, format='%d/%m/%Y  %H:%M')
df['pub_day'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df.pub).normalize()

df.set_index('pub', inplace=True)

#add columns pub_day (for grouping), and other columns for aggregating (counted_if, 20, ...)
df1 = df[['pub_day', 'counted_if','20']].groupby('pub_day').transform('sum').reset_index()
print df1
                  pub  counted_if  20
0 2002-02-02 13:03:00          48  34
1 2002-02-02 11:08:00          48  34
2 2002-02-01 17:30:00           3   8
3 2002-01-31 11:03:00          10  26
4 2002-01-31 09:03:00          10  26
5 2002-01-26 08:07:00           6   3
```

```
#if date in pub_date and pub is same, use dt.date
df1['pub_day'] = df1['pub'].dt.date 
print df1
                  pub  counted_if  20     pub_day
0 2002-02-02 13:03:00          48  34  2002-02-02
1 2002-02-02 11:08:00          48  34  2002-02-02
2 2002-02-01 17:30:00           3   8  2002-02-01
3 2002-01-31 11:03:00          10  26  2002-01-31
4 2002-01-31 09:03:00          10  26  2002-01-31
5 2002-01-26 08:07:00           6   3  2002-01-26

df2=df1.drop_duplicates(subset='pub_day',keep='first')
print df2
                  pub  counted_if  20     pub_day
0 2002-02-02 13:03:00          48  34  2002-02-02
2 2002-02-01 17:30:00           3   8  2002-02-01
3 2002-01-31 11:03:00          10  26  2002-01-31
5 2002-01-26 08:07:00           6   3  2002-01-26

#add other columns for aggregating (counted_if, 20, ...), column pub_day is for new index
df2=df2[['counted_if','pub_day', '20']] 
print df2
   counted_if     pub_day  20
0          48  2002-02-02  34
2           3  2002-02-01   8
3          10  2002-01-31  26
5           6  2002-01-26   3
```

```
df2.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)
df2.set_index('pub_day', inplace=True)

idx=pd.date_range(df2.index.min(),df2.index.max())
#print idx

df2=df2.reindex(idx,fill_value=0)
print df2
            counted_if  20
2002-01-26           6   3
2002-01-27           0   0
2002-01-28           0   0
2002-01-29           0   0
2002-01-30           0   0
2002-01-31          10  26
2002-02-01           3   8
2002-02-02          48  34
```

Comment: Sure no worries! :) - Actually there is maybe one minor add on question here for those who might be interested: Asssume we have multiple counted-if columns based on groupby's (all integers) and we just want to print - lets say 4 columns - by >>> print s.simply     s=output.colums['counted_if1','counted_if2','counted_if3','counted_if4'] in your respective line?

Comment: This gives a key error on 'pub_day' for the following line then:
df2=df1.drop_duplicates(subset=['pub_day'],keep='first')

Comment: I mean, how for instance make it finally look sth like this:

                         ['counted_if']           ['20']
2002-01-26                6                      3
2002-01-27                0                      0
2002-01-28                0                      0
2002-01-29                0                      0
2002-01-30                0                      0
2002-01-31                5                     26
2002-02-01                3                      8
2002-02-02               24                    34

Comment: One question - `dates` in columns `pub` and `pub_day` are same?

Comment: yes, but 'pub_day' is normalized as stated above to a daily level hence hours and minutes in 'pub_day' become 00 each. For 'pub' they are filled with particular hours and minutes

Comment: Just checked it there is still one issue with this, jjust give me two mins for an illustrative update.

Comment: Here we go again. Could it be sth in here?:
df1 = df[['pub_day', 'counted_if','20']].groupby('pub_day').transform('sum').reset_index() ?

Comment: Got the error: Your solution works perfectly fine, i just doubled a groupby operation in some conditional loop....

Thank you so much, this is literally a.m.a.z.i.n.g!